# My job seems to be ignoring a state executive order to suspend activity. How can I best protect myself but also report them to the authorities?

Tags: united-states, business, michigan, covid-19

Michigan has issued an order titled "[Temporary requirement to suspend activities that
are not necessary to sustain or protect life](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/0rLaAkfMoi/files)". In it they reference [Homeland Security's own guidance about what constitutes essential critical infrastructure](https://www.cisa.gov/sites/default/files/publications/CISA-Guidance-on-Essential-Critical-Infrastructure-Workers-1-20-508c.pdf) as the businesses to remain in operation.

While the Michigan order allows individuals to recreate outdoors. And that recreation may take the form of cycling while maintaining 6 feet of separation. However, it seems pretty clear to me that businesses supporting recreational activities are not essential critical infrastructure. This seems exactly the kind of word twisting Gamestop was using to remain open before being shut down.

How can I best bring this to the attention of authorities while balancing my own professional security?

Answer (score 2):

Since [violation of the order is a misdemeanor](https://www.michigan.gov/whitmer/0,9309,7-387-90499_90705-522626--,00.html), you may report it to the local police. It is up to them, and the district attorney, to decide whether this is important enough that they will take action. If you want your name to not be associated with the report, you can try reporting anonymously, though that may require mailing an anonymous letter to the local police.

Comment: Honestly, it's not clear whether, say, a cycling shop falls under the transportation exemption or not. Contacting the police would at least inform you what their interpretation is.

Answer (score 0):

User6726 has the right answer.    However I would like to add two things to that answer that are a little different:

1. Just call the police and report them.    Call from a friend's cell phone if you need to but there is no reason that the police need to know your name nor is there any reason they would pass this on to the offender.   Some states have ordinances that citizens can enforce misdemeanor activity or witness testimony would solely be used but in reality this is only played out in Florida (joke).   Just call them and hopefully a call from them to your employer will shut things down without them getting in trouble.
2. Your employer is probably setting themselves up for some mighty mighty liability as since they are violating a specific order and the order is directly about a singular virus, it is pretty easy to connect the dots and see this exposes them to a lot of civil action exposure if someone at your workplace got sick.   I mean they would be paying at the very least hospital bills, for the time off, and a decent amount for pain and suffering - a bicycle rental place would go bankrupt instantly and depending how their business was created the owner could possibly be liable.